# ffmpeg not encoding 'container' correctly

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, flowplayer

I am trying to encode a file that is uploaded to our server using ffmpeg.

However, when we play the video through any flash based media player (FlowPlayer, JW Player) it plays the audio but no video. When we play it on a desktop application (VLC, QT, WMP) - it works fine.

Here is my encoding command:

`/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i {$in} -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ac 2 -b 300 -threads 4 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions 0 -subq 1 -trellis 0 -refs 1 -coder 0 -bufsize 10M  -qcomp 0.6 -qmax 22 -qdiff 4 -level 30 {$out}`

`{$in}` is the input file, `{$out}` is the output file.

Our ffmpeg version is `N-41485-g1321e6e-syslint`

I am still somewhat new to the video encoding scene, can anyone see anything with my encode string that might be a giveaway?

Comment: What kind of container are you storing your file in? Also, what version of Flash are you using on your client?

Comment: MP4 is the container type. My flash version is 11.3 i believe. It happens on all computers we test it on though, its not my version of flash..

Comment: It's been a while since I've dealt with this, but have you tried changing the extension of your mp4 to flv?